# Basic loop (excel not recognizing code consistently)

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am doing a sales dashboard using vba in excel and I have been having trouble with this loop. I have used the same loop multiple times and sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesnt. Excel keeps looping and does not recognize the criteria to stop looping.

```
Do Until (Worksheets("aerolineas").Range("xaa3").Offset(Z, 0).Text = cmbAirlines.Text)
    Z = Z + 1      
Loop
```

Another example where the loop sometimes doesn't work

```
Do
    J = J + 1
Loop Until (ActiveSheet.Cells(13, 1).Offset(J, 0).Value = cmbAgents)
```

I think it may have to do with the `.Value` and `.text` but I have tried both and I can't figure out what's wrong! Like I said, sometimes the loop works fine, sometimes it keep looping until it says: "Overflow"

I would appreciate your help! I have been struggling with these for days!

Comment: is the "value" in your `Cells` or `Range` is inside a formula? or constant text ?

Answer (score 0):

your overflow is likely to derive by any declaration of `Z` and `J` variables as of `Integer` type, which is limited to maximum value of 32767

so you can try and declare them as of `Long` type

other than that, you could skip loops by use of `Find(`) method:

for instance your first code would become

```
Dim found As Range
Set found = Worksheets("aerolineas").Range("xaa:xaa").Find(what:=cmbAirlines.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not found Is Nothing Then
    'your code to exploit 'found' range
    MsgBox "found vale at row: " & found.row
End If
```

and your second code would become:

```
Dim found As Range
Set found = Range("A13", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=cmbAgents.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not found Is Nothing Then
    'your code to exploit 'found' range
    MsgBox "found vale at row: " & found.row
End If
```